# How to update badgeText in Sencha Touch (Ext.Container)

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Currently I'm a newbie in Sencha and I want to update the badgeText in Sencha Touch from the store count in Ext.Container.

Please see my code below for your reference:

```
 Ext.define('XX.view.Menu',{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'menu',
    config: {
        cls: 'mainmenu',
        docked: 'left',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        zIndex: 0,
        width: 266,
        padding: '0 0 0 0',
        open: false,
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        defaultType: 'button',
        defaults: {
            textAlign: 'left'
        },
        scrollable: {
            indicators: false
        },
        items: [{
            text: 'Home',
            ui: 'mainmenu',
            iconCls: 'home',
            itemId: 'home'
        },{
            text: 'Contact Us',
            ui: 'mainmenu',
            iconCls: 'form',
            itemId: 'contactus'
        },{
            text : 'Notifications',
            ui: 'mainmenu',
            badgeText: '0',
            iconCls: 'form',
            itemId: 'notifications'
        }]
    },

    setParent: function(parent) {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.maskCmp = parent.add({
            xtype   : 'component',
            cls     : 'mainmenu-mask',
            top     : 0,
            zIndex  : 5000,
            hidden  : true,
            width   : 9999,
            left    : this.getWidth(),
            bottom  : 0
        });

        this.maskCmp.element.on({
            scope   : this,
            touchend: 'onMaskRelease'
        });

    }




});
```

EDIT:
 This one is working as per Sujata's - Tap Event

```
     config: {
    refs: {
        notificationsMenuItem: 'menu #notifications'
    },
    control: {

        notificationsMenuItem: {
            tap: 'notificationsItemTap'
        }
    }
}

notificationsItemTap: function(button){
    button.setBadgeText('1');
}
```

EDIT: UPDATE-02 - Working Modified Code as per Sujata's latest reply:

```
  config: {
    refs: {
        notificationsMenuItem: 'menu #notifications'
    }
},
    control: {
        main: {
            initialize: 'mainInitialize',
            navigationMode: 'switchToNavigation'
        }
    },
    mainInitialize: function() {
    this.getNotificationsMenuItem().setBadgeText('48');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it with the `setBadgeText` method. Add 'name: "notifications"' field in your button view. In the controller get the refs of the button like this:

```
refs: {
   notificationsBtn : 'button[name="notifications"]'  
}
```

Get the button tap event :

```
control: {
   notificationsBtn : {
      tap : function(btn) {
           btn.setBadgeText('1');  // Get your store data and set
      }
 }
```

**Edit:-**

To get the badge text on menu load you can use the initialize method of the view, like this:-

```
    refs: {
      menu: 'menu',
      notificationsBtn : 'button[name="notifications"]'  
    },
    control: {
       menu : {
         initialize :  function(){
          this.getNotificationsBtn().setBadgeText('1');
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Sujata, Thank you very much for your reply. Currently this 'XX.view.Menu' doesn't have controller, so if I'll get the refs to put in another controller who will be indicating the badgeText, what will be the format?

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand what you want. Can you please clear it out. Do you need to set the badgeText at `setParent` method?

Comment: Hi @Sujata I've already edit the code above. Hope I've explained it clearly. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: I have edited my code. Check whether it works or not.

Comment: Vanakkam @Sujata, it's working! You save my life lol. Thank you very much!